# Leave an echo statement empty

Tags: php

I was just wondering is it acceptable to leave an echo statement empty, for example my code below works great, I was just after some advice to make sure it's acceptable/safe, or perhaps is there a way i can safely remove the first echo statement, thank you very much

```
    <?php
        if (empty($page['data'])) {
            echo "";
        } else {
            echo "something in here;
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: sure, why not? nothing wrong with that. You can do `if (empty($page['data'])) {
            
        }` it's valid.

Comment: You can also leave the entire bracket empty. Or just simply do `if (!empty($page['data'])) { echo "something in here; }`

Comment: you could even shorten that to a ternary operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "echo" an empty string, you formally can even drop the whole `echo` statement, though it looks strange:

```
<?php
if (empty($page['data'])) {
} else {
    echo "something in here";
}
```

The obvious alternative is a negation:

```
<?php
if (!empty($page['data'])) {
    echo "something in here";
}
```

Comment: @Fred-ii- I did, but apparently I am too dumb and cannot match your fine sense of detail.

Comment: @arkascha I guess their question could have swung either way. I suggested a ternary operator up there, but that's just me ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I can't follow. Certainly an echo statement with a ternary operator is valid, but it does not change the scope of the question, since it is still no answered if an empty argument to an `echo` statement is valid. But that is just my 2 cents. As said: "prolly" I am simply too dumb and tired for such stuff...

Comment: @arkascha Hard to say really, since their question IMHO is a tad unclear/too broad. The `!empty()` you posted would be shorter in what they seem to want to do and not using an `else{}` but from what I took from the question was that not having an echo inside a conditional is perfectly valid; hence my comment up there ;-)